# Quel est le sens de l'abréviation ETS

Tags: sens, abréviations

J'ai souvent vu écrit *ETS* sur des panneaux d'entreprise et je n'arrive pas à en trouver le sens. Par exemple **ETS TONON VIRAZEIL**

---

In the context of a business or an enterprise what does *ETS* mean. An example would be **ETS TONON VIRAZEIL**

Comment: En tant qu'acronyme, ça peut désigner une *École de Technologie Supérieure*, éventuellement (pour la complétude, pas dans le cadre d'une entreprise).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une abréviation d'*établissements*. Voir par exemple [Ets
English translation: établissements](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/french_to_english/law%3A_contracts/828931-ets.html) ou [Abréviations et sigles](http://j.poitou.free.fr/pro/html/typ/abrev.html).

Comment: bien lien: http://j.poitou.free.fr/pro/html/typ/abrev.html merci.

Answer (score 0):

Cela signifie : Établissement.